# Django: How to load dynamic data to chartjs

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, chart.js

I want to load my models' data into a chart, using chartjs.

Curiously, only the 'dummy-data' is working, that looks as follow:

```
data: {
        labels: ['red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
                            datasets: [{
                                label: '# of Votes',
                                data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 7],
```

My raw data looks like this:

```
labels = ['/truck-alerts-analysis/fleet-history', '/truck-alerts-analysis/map-view', 
          '/truck-alerts-analysis/fleet-status', '/truck-alerts-analy
          sis/truck-history', '/truck-alerts-analysis/truck-history', '/truck-alerts- 
          analysis/fleet-status', '/truck-alerts-analysis/truck-histor
          y', '/setup/QCFcKp', '/reset-password', '/login']


data = [251, 243, 238, 220, 174, 158, 151, 88, 87, 86]
```

Using django, I defined these values in views.py as follow:

```
def pages(request):
    showData = start_date
    pageV = PageView.objects.all()
    FPage = FinalPage.objects.all()

    typeUser = list(FinalPage.objects.values_list('page', flat=True))
    count = list(FinalPage.objects.values_list('sessionCount', flat=True))

    # manipulation in order to get the right labels that I want
    t=[]
    for i in typeUser:
        new = i.split("?", 1)[0]
        t.append(new)

    k = t[-10:]
    c = count[-10:]

    # Where the labels and data is being returned 
    return render(request, 'gaapp/pages.html', {"showData": showData,
                                                "labels": k,
                                                "data": c})
```

The curious behaviour is that, when calling for `{{labels}}` and `{{data}}` in the HTML file (where the chart is being processed), only the `{{data}}` is being excepted? In other words, the `{{labels}}` aren't valid. I don't understand why? Please help

My HTML:

```
<div class="PageMines">
        <canvas id="myChart1" width="40" height="30"></canvas>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart1').getContext('2d');

                    var myChart1 = new Chart(ctx, {
                        type: 'bar',
                        data: {
                            labels: {{names}},
                            datasets: [{
                                label: '# of Votes',
                                data: {{numbers}},

                                backgroundColor: [
                                    'blue',
                                    'blue',
                                    'blue',
                                    'blue',
                                    'blue',
                                    'blue',
                                ],
                                borderColor: [
                                    'blue',
                                    'blue',
                                    'blue',
                                    'blue',
                                    'blue',
                                    'blue',
                                ],
                                borderWidth: 1
                            }]
                        },
                        options: {


                            scales: {

                                yAxes: [{
                                    ticks: {
                                        beginAtZero: true

                                    }

                                }]
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });
            </script>
            </div>
```

Comment: In render function, You returned context with {"labels": xx, "data": xx }. In html, trying to access it with {{ names }} & {{ numbers }}. There is a miss-match, isn't it?